# Can you use “comment” like “que” (that)?

Tags: sens, conjonctions

> C'est Albert qui nous a appris **comment** l’empereur est mort.
>
> = "It’s Albert who has told us **that** the emperor has passed."

Normally, “comment” translates into “how”, but it seems to me that the “comment” here serves the function of “que” (that) rather than asking about the way (*façon*, *manière*) the emperor has passed.

Comment: I do agree with you that “comment” is sometimes used as in “comment la situation se présente”, relating the state and not the reason that led to this situation. You won't convince anyone of that here unless you give more context, but I believe it's possible and should not be ruled out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Comment" always translates to "how" : If I translate the French example "C'est Albert qui nous a appris comment l’empereur est mort.", you know **how** the emperor has passed. Comment = La manière, le moyen

Here is another example:

> Il nous a appris **comment** conduire un tramway.
>
> He taught us **how** to drive a tram.